# c# regex match with string comparison (finding smallest value)

Tags: c#, regex

I am completely stumped on how to achieve this. Basically, I want to find the ceiling in a METAR report. The ceiling is the smallest broken or overcast layer.

I currently have this (which is not much by any means):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(modify, @"(BKN|OVC)([0-9]{3})");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
    {
        // compare broken and overcast layers to find smallest value and set as the ceiling
        Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
    }
}
```

Basically this searches the METAR string for BKN or OVC layers and spits them out. Take this METAR reading for example:

`PANC 040553Z 17013G24KT 280V360 2SM FEW050 BKN019 BKN008 OVC005 14/M07 A2999 RMK AO2 SLP156 SH DSNT W-N T01390067 10167 20139 53002`

The code I currently have will spit out BKN019, BKN008 and OVC005. What I need to do, is pick the smallest of these values (which, in this case, would be OVC005).

If someone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a better definition of "smallest value".  Why is `OVC005` the smallest?  Is it based on the numerical portion of the string?

Comment: Yes, it's based on the numerical portion of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using capturing groups:

```
// (?<number> names the group that captures the number value
var matches = Regex.Matches(modify, @"(BKN|OVC)(?<number>[0-9]{3})");

// cast to IEnumerable<Match>()
var smallest = matches.Cast<Match>()
    // order by the parsed number group
    // Added `.Value` to make this work
    .OrderBy(m => int.Parse(m.Groups["number"].Value))
    // Select the string value
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    // take the first (the smallest)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

if smallest is `null` then no matches found

Comment: +1 but this would return smallest number only..i guess op needs complete match

Comment: Minor issue is that if there are no matches this will throw an exception

Comment: Just change `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault` and you'll get a `null` value instead of the smallest number. Just put in a check for `null`, which means no matches.

Comment: I get two erros when I use this:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group' to 'string'`
and
`The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @Spence add `.Value` after `m.Groups["number"]` and before the closing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do is keep track of the lowest layer found so far and then check for each regex match whether it's lower than before:

```
int lowestLayer = int.MaxValue;
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(modify, @"(BKN|OVC)([0-9]{3})");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
    {
        int layer = int.Parse(capture.Value.Substring(3));
        if (layer < lowestLayer)
            lowestLayer = layer;
        Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the whole capture for the smallest 2nd group.

```
matches.OfType<Match>()
       .Select(m => new { Capture = m.Groups[0], Number = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2]) })
       .OrderBy(m =­> m.Number)
       .Select(m => m.Capture)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: As I've just realized with my answer, the extra select is unnecessary, just use int.parse line directly in the order by.

Answer (score 0):

`Linq` is your friend

remember `using System.Linq`

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(modify, @"(BKN|OVC)([0-9]{3})");
var first = (
             from x in matches.OfType<Match>()
             orderby int.Parse(x.Groups[2].Value)
             select x.Value
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```